# ScrollView Crahses the phonegap app in windows phone

Tags: jquery, windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile

i have an issue that i use jquery mobile scrollview in my phonegap app and it runs well in iOS

& Android and BB OS but in windows phone phonegap it crashes the app  and in browser it does not scroll but scroll bar is exist

any Help ?!